# Lubuntu gives a graphics error, Ubuntu installs fine?

Tags: preinstallation

I downloaded L-Ubuntu x86, installed it to a USB drive using YUMI-2.0.4.2.  Did the same with Ubuntu.  Ubuntu will install, L-Ubuntu gives a graphics error.  Tried this 3 times after downloading and using L-Ubuntu three times.  Any ideas on how I can get L-Ubuntu to install?